Special char not recognized and text illegible in a PDF generated with jspdf and html2canvas
i having exact same problem as this person but coudn't found the solution to fix it
check this code to see the problem https://github.com/parallax/jsPDF/issues/2832
i tried to degrade the package version from 2 to 1.5.3 but still the same error
this is my function
async downloadPDF(ids) {
this.isActive2 = true;
try {
    await this.Trackgo(ids);
    this.isGeneratingPDF = true;
    
    await this.$nextTick(); // Ensure DOM updates

    let pdfContent = this.$refs.pdfContent;

    // Check if pdfContent is correctly referenced
    if (!pdfContent) {
        throw new Error('pdfContent ref is not found');
    }

    // Use html2canvas to capture the content
    const canvas = await html2canvas(pdfContent, { scale: 2 });
    const imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');

    var imgWidth = 203; 
    var pageHeight = 295;  
    var imgHeight = canvas.height * imgWidth / canvas.width;
    var heightLeft = imgHeight;
    //console.log(canvas.height);
    //console.log(canvas.width);
    
    var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'mm');
    var position = 0;
    
    //console.log(imgHeight);

    // Add the first page
    doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 4, position, imgWidth, imgHeight, undefined, 'FAST');
    heightLeft -= pageHeight;
    //console.log(heightLeft);
    // Add remaining pages if the content overflows
    while (heightLeft > 0) {
        position = heightLeft - imgHeight;
        doc.addPage();
        doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 4, position, imgWidth, imgHeight, undefined, 'FAST');
        heightLeft -= pageHeight;
    }

    // Save the PDF
    doc.save("newpdf.pdf");

} catch (error) {
    console.error('PDF generation failed', error);
} finally {
    this.isGeneratingPDF = false;
    this.isActive2 = false;
}

},

Issues with third party libraries should be reported on the appropriate github page. According to the github issue you linked, the issue should've been fixed in a newer version. Maybe it regressed again. Seems more appropriate to bring it up with the maintainer(s) than Stack Overflow.
